# Are "окидывать взглядом" and "заглядывать" interchangeable?

Tags: словоупотребление, лексикон

As far as I can tell, both окидывать взглядом and заглядывать have the same general meaning. Are there any nuances that they don't share? Is one more colloquial?

Comment: Please avoid uppercase for just separating cyrillic letters from latin ones.

Comment: Is that your personal preference, or a "rule"?

Comment: That is a common sense of how capital letters are supposed to used, if you don't like it,  you can raise an issue on meta.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but thanks for responding :) PS: It's not common sense - "all caps" are used in titles all the time.

Comment: show  me some another linguistic SE site where it is the case and we'll have a talk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they don't have the same general meaning. **"Заглядывать-заглянуть + Accusative (куда?)"** means "to peep in", "to look into", "to have a look at" or "to drop in", "to call in". So, normally this verb means "to look inside smth" or "to come, enter somewhere":

Я заглянул в книгу.
I looked into the book.

Она часто заглядывала к нам.
She used to call in to our place often.

**"Окидывать-окинуть взглядом + Accusative (кого? что?)"** means "to glance over", "to rake". It has the meaning of looking attentively and having a wide space to look at.

Профессор окинул взглядом всю аудиторию.
The professor glanced over the whole audience.

As you can also see, "заглядывать-заглянуть" is always used with a preposition, while "окидывать-окинуть взглядом" is used with a direct object.

"Окидывать-окинуть взглядом" is a synonym of "оглядывать-оглянуть + Accusative (кого? что?)" which also means "to take a view of", "to look over (round)", but has a nuance in the meaning because it can also be "to examine":

Профессор оглянул всю аудиторию.
The professor looked over the whole audience.

Что ты меня оглядываешь?
Why are you examining me?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a few meanings and use cases of `заглядывать`.

- "Заглядывать вперёд" means "to look forward", but it can not be as "<s>оглядывать вперёд</s>", it's incorrect. However it **is** possible (and widely used) to say:
- "Оглядываться назад"(1) means "To look back", e.g. when *someone's walking* or in terms of *passed days*, or *time that has gone* (look back into the history) but can not be "<s>оглядывать назад</s>", it's incorrect. However it **is** possible (and widely used) to say:
- "Заглядывать назад" means also "To look back" is also can be said in terms of *passed days*, or *time that has gone*, can **not** be said when someone's is walking, more likely wheh is not moving -sitting or standing.
- "Он заглядывается на других девушек" means "He looks at other girls", it **is** possible to say "Он оглядывается на др  девушек" but this means that "He turns his head around to watch other girls(when passing by them)"
- "Заглядывать в душу" means "To look into the soul" but it can not be as "<s>оглядывать душу"</s>

(1)"я оглянулся посмотреть не оглянулась ли она чтоб посмотреть не оглянулся ли я" words from a famous song, means "I looked around to see if she did not look back to see if I did not look back"